# Program to print a triangle of numbers

Tags: c#, formatting

I want to print the following triangle:

> ```
> 1
> 1  2
> 1  2  3
> 1  2  3  4
> 1  2  3  4  5
> 1  2  3  4
> 1  2  3
> 1  2
> 1
> ```

I tried to do but I cannot avoid two `for` loops. Is it possible to achieve the result in a single `for` loop?

```
 static void printtriangle()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            Console.Write("" + (j));

        }
        Console.WriteLine("");

    }


        for (int k = 4; k >= 0; --k)
        {

            for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("" + (k));

            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
         }

    }
```

Comment: Why would you want it to be done in a single for-loop?

Comment: By the way, technically you have four for-loops right now. What do you mean by one for-loop?

Comment: I am using four for loops. I am trying to finish the work within two loops so as to reduce the loops and increase the performance of the code. I mean increasing execution speed and reducing the overheads associated of loop

Comment: In the above code I have kept the maximum limit of triangle to 5. What if I increase it to 1000?. Will there be drop in performance due to nested loops?

Comment: Perforance wise, the looping is irrelevant. Most of the time will be spent writing the characters to the console.

Comment: A quick performance test shows that about 99.7% of the time is spent in the `Console` calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with one loop that goes from a negative number to a positive, and create a string from a range calculated from the number:

```
int max = 5;
for (int i = 1 - max; i < max; i++) {
  Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", Enumerable.Range(1, max - Math.Abs(i))));
}
```

That is of course actually two loops, the `Range` method will create numbers that the `Join` method loops through.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with a string of values separated by a space.  Then printout a substring of that according to the loop variable:

```
static void PrintTri(int limit)
{
    if(limit > 1)
    {
        string temp = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= limit; i++)
        {
            temp += i.ToString() + " ";
            Console.WriteLine(temp.Substring(0, i * 2));
        }
        for(int i = limit - 1; i >=0; i--)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(temp.Substring(0, i * 2));
        }
    }            
}
```

As for performance, building new strings against using 2 loops will need to be tested.